# Facebook Like Image gets cropped/cut-off

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'm having a problem where the image that is pulled through to the user's wall after they click the like button is cropped.  See link for image:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/36/fblikeimage.jpg/

Here is my iFrame code:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.org&amp;send=false&amp;layout=box_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=recommend&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=90&amp;appId=1234" 
width="320" height="60"></iframe>
```

Here are my OG tags:

```
<meta content="123456879" property="fb:app_id"> 
<meta content="sch_donations:donate" property="og:type"> 
<meta content="https://mysite.org/?utm_source=internal&amp;utm_medium=social&amp;utm_content=recommend-on-facebook&amp;utm_campaign=WTH-FB" property="og:url"> 
<meta content="Title text" property="og:title"> 
<meta content="Description text" property="og:description"> 
<meta content="https://mysite.org/image.jpg" property="og:image"> 
<meta content="https://mysite.org/?utm_source=internal&amp;utm_medium=social&amp;utm_content=recommend-on-facebook&amp;utm_campaign=WTH-FB" property="sch_donations:link">
```

I wondered if anyone else has come across this problem?  Can you see anything in my code that might cause this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the image is the problem... What are its original dimensions? Fb tends to crop it like that if an image doesn't have its height and width equal...

Comment: I've just checked and it's 88x87, so not quite square.  I'll swap the image out and see how I get on.  Thanks.

Comment: I've changed the image URl to an image that is 87x87 but facebook stil insists on picking up he old image URL.  I've ran the page through the linter, which should clear the cache but it's still showing the old image.  Any thoughts?

Comment: can You share the link to Your picture?